# Coming soon pages with rest of site in maintenance mode

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, permalinks, maintenance

I already created a custom plugin but am officially stuck!

I need to create coming soon page that:

- Includes option to sign up for newsletter
- Link to privacy section
- Thank you page after signing up to newsletter

I'm tried re-directing user with .htaccess mod but this requires white-listing multiple IP addresses to grant access. Another caveat to the previous implementation is that we are going to create a sub-domain to host additional content and would like the domain to host landing page content.

I've instead decided to use WordPress maintenance mode function to create a custom plugin. However, the problem is I cannot successfully redirect users to both "privacy" and "thank you" pages without having the links look long and awful. Landing page is OK and is mydomain.com

Privacy page looks like following:

*mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/maintenance-domain/views/privacy.php*

I would rather it look like *mydomain.com/privacy.php*

The question is wow can I make my wp-maintenance page link to another page while still maintaining a pretty permalink structure? In other words it seems that I am limited to a single page implementation while using wp maintenance mode.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Darth_Vader Guess it is a bit unclear.... How can I make my maintenance page link to another page while still maintaining a pretty permalink structure? In other words it seems that I am limited to a single page implementation while using wp maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer to above solution but I have something that works well enough for now.

Put other pages I need to link to ("thank you" & "privacy") is a folder inside the root name "n."

The end result are links that are good enough and not confusing to end users.